# How to explode a single column of dictionaries of varying lengths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with one column, "articles", that has dictionaries as values. Some dictionaries contain multiple values. You can see the number of 'text' values in the dictionary of the articles column in the column titled "article_amt".

[image: screen shot of full dataframe]

I want to explode that column so that each key of the dictionary is its own column in the dataframe. I have been able to convert the articles column into its own dataframe, but I no longer have the species information when I do so, which I need. Here is an example of the dataframe of just the "articles" column

[image: screenshot of articles dataframe]

My goal is to end up with a dataframe with all of the columns listed in both screencaps, with repeating rows for the species-specific information for as many articles as each species has. I have browsed some similar questions online but they result in unnecessary columns for me or placing the keys from the articles column as the index. My data is rather large so I can't paste a sample in here but a simplified example should be:

```
data = {'age': [59, 18, 63],
    'sample':  [({'0': {'a':'yes', 'b': 'no'}, '1':{'a': 'maybe', 'b': 'NA'}}), ({'0': {'a':'no', 'b': 'yes'}}),  ({'0': {'a':'no', 'b': 'no'}, '1':{'a': 'no', 'b': 'yes'}, '2':{'a': 'yes', 'b': 'yes'}})],
    'date': ['2022-09-29', '2022-08-29', '2022-07-29']}
```

I have tried the following solution:

```
pd.concat(t['sample'].apply(pd.DataFrame).tolist(), 
                    keys=t["age"]).reset_index(level="age")
```

And get the following:

[image]

I want the keys, "a" and "b" to be included as columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`explode` the dict values in `sample` then create a intermediate dataframe from the exploded values and join back with original dataframe

```
s = df['sample'].map(dict.values).explode()
df.drop(columns=['sample']).join(pd.DataFrame([*s], s.index))
```

Result

```
   age        date      a    b
0   59  2022-09-29    yes   no
0   59  2022-09-29  maybe   NA
1   18  2022-08-29     no  yes
2   63  2022-07-29     no   no
2   63  2022-07-29     no  yes
2   63  2022-07-29    yes  yes
```

Comment: It seems to work for the sample data, but not the original dataset, so I have to investigate what's causing the error. but thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rework the output of [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
out = df.drop(columns='sample').join(
 pd.json_normalize(df['sample'])
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.str.split('.', expand=True), axis=1))
   .stack().rename_axis([None, 'new']).reset_index(-1)
)
```

Output:

```
   age        date new    0      1    2
0   59  2022-09-29   a  yes  maybe  NaN
0   59  2022-09-29   b   no     NA  NaN
1   18  2022-08-29   a   no    NaN  NaN
1   18  2022-08-29   b  yes    NaN  NaN
2   63  2022-07-29   a   no     no  yes
2   63  2022-07-29   b   no    yes  yes
```

Comment: this still results in the values of a and b as their own columns. I would want their values (aka the values currently listed under 0, 1, and 2) to be listed under a and b

Comment: I thought this was the expected output, please provide the explicit expected output that matches your input for clarity